# Are all connected graphs with degree sequence $(2,2,4,4,6)$ Hamiltonian?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonicity

> Are all connected graphs with degree sequence $(2,2,4,4,6)$ Hamiltonian?

---

*I have the following few observations:*

Note that there are only $5$ vertices but the highest degree is $6$. Hence the graph is not simple.

It may contain loops or multi-edges. The vertices of degree $2$ can't contain any loops since the graph is connected.

Note that we can't apply Dirac's Theorem or Ore's Theorem since the graph is not simple.

---

I tried finding an example but failed.

Need some help.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your logic. I would say "Since there are only $5$ vertices but the highest degree is $6$, there are no graphs with this degree sequence. Therefore all graphs with this degree sequence are Hamiltonian." However, either way, we can ask if there are non-Hamiltonian multigraphs.

Comment: @MishaLavrov We can consider graphs that are not simple.

Comment: Terminology varies; both in the context of degree sequences and of Hamiltonian cycles, I would usually assume that "graph" means "simple graph", so I would double-check if your source assumes this as well. As I said, it makes sense either way to look for non-Hamiltonian multigraphs with this degree sequence. *(Hint: what if a vertex of degree $2$ has $2$ edges to the same vertex?)*

Comment: Since the existence of a Hamilton cycle is not altered by deleting multiple edges and loops, you could start with a multigraph with degree sequence (2,6) and build the multigraph with degree-sequence (2,2,4,4,6) from that. The reduced ordinary graph will have a bridge.